# In Talend Studio in tFileOutputDelimited what does 'OS line separator as row separator' do?

Tags: csv, talend

In Talend Studio (at least in versions 7.3.1 and 8.0.1), the component tFileOutputDelimited has a checkbox that says

> ***Use OS line separator as row separator when CSV Row Separator is set to CR, LF or CRLF***.

And right below there's a dropdown menu with only 3 options:

- ***LF ("\n")***
- ***CR ("\r")***
- ***CRLF ("\r\n")***

[image: Screenshot of Talend Studio: a checkbox and a dropdown menu]

What's the difference between checking or unchecking the checkbox? What does it do?

What's the difference between an ***OS line separator*** and a ***CSV row separator***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the option "Use OS line separator", and in the CSV Row Separator you set one of the 3 delimiters (LF, CR, CRLF), when the job is executed it automatically selects the appropriate row separator for the OS it's running on (LF for Linux, CRLF for Windows). It's a nice feature if your job is deployed to a different OS and you want your file to have the right separator for that platform, without having to modify your job.
If you set the option "Use OS line separator" but you set a custom line separator, Talend will use the separator you specify, so the option doesn't really matter.
If you uncheck the option "Use OS line separator", you can specify the separator that will always be used regardless of the underlying OS.